# Page level filters initially appear on all pages

Tags: powerbi-embedded

#### Problem

When I apply report-level filters and page-level filters, all the page-level filter cards appear on all the pages until the user clicks to another page and back.  They aren't actively filtering those pages, however, just incorrectly appearing there.

#### Example

In the screenshot, the other two pages in the report should have their own "Country" filter, but the cards appear in the "Filters on this page" part of the Filters panel, even though they're not affecting this page.  When you click to one of those other pages and click back to this one, those cards are gone.  The problem is just on the initial load (they just shouldn't appear here).

#### Implementation of `setFilters`

```js
report.setFilters(filters)
countryPage.setFilters(countryPageFilters)
categoryPage.setFilters(categoryPageFilters)
```

where `filters`, `countryPageFilters`, and `categoryPageFilters` are both arrays of `filter` objects. I set filters individually on each page where relevant, and then a separate set that acts across all pages of the report.

#### Tried

- I could hide those page level filters, but the user needs to be able to adjust them.
- Tried re-arranging the order of setting the filters
- Tried initializing an empty array of filters in the `embedConfig` object for report-level and each page-level of filters.

#### Background

Using powerbi-client package v2.11.0 with a Vue.js project.

[image: PowerBI Filters panel showing the Filters on this page which includes filters that don't apply to this page]